# How to display argument in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script called displayArg.sh This is how I intend to run it-

```
./displayArg hello
```

and the output is **entered arg is hello**

The following is the script-

```
if [ $1 == "" ]; then
 default="Default"
 echo "no value is given. Output is $default"
else
 value=$?
 echo "entered arg is $value" #I know I am wrong in these 2 lines, but not sure how to fix it
fi
```

Kindly bear with me. I'm new to Shell scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
value="$1"
```

(`$?` is the status of the last command, which is 1 because the test command is what was executed last.)

Or you can simplify to:

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
    echo "no value is given. Output is Default"
else
    echo "entered arg is $1"
fi
```

Note the quotes around `"$1"` in the test.  If the string is empty, you get a syntax error.  Your alternative with `bash` is to use a `[[ $1 == "" ]]` test.